# Thumb clipped inside polygon (triangle)

Tags: c#, wpf

At the moment I'm able to move a thumb in a rectangular canvas.

```
<Canvas ClipToBounds="false">
    <Thumb Canvas.Left="-5" Canvas.Top="-5" x:Name="PART_Thumb" Style="{StaticResource HsvControlThumbStyle}">
        <Thumb.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
        </Thumb.RenderTransform>
    </Thumb>
</Canvas>
```

Is there an easy way to have this thumb movement clipped inside a polygon or a path maybe ?

Thank you